# Retrieve position of a google maps v3 marker to Qt in a desktop app with QtWebKit

Tags: javascript, qt, google-maps, qtwebkit, qwebview

I'm building a Qt app with Python where you can point and click at a (google) map and get the coordinates of the location. The map is shown through a `QWebView` loading a simple HTML page and the user can create markers by clicking. [Screenshot](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_fwC09vRdEJ4/S_c1KlmdJeI/AAAAAAAAA1c/hpYvF5jmkH0/geo_shot.png) of the widget after clicking on the map.

However, I'm having trouble to retrieve the just-clicked location coordinates back to Qt (so that I can use them as variables -- and, for example, show them in the `QLineEdit`s on the topleft corner above, as current location of the marker).

This is the relevant part of the HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initialize() { 
    var local = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.4,-40.3);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: local,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    } 
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
    var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });

    map.setCenter(location);
}

function dummyTxt() {
    return 'This works.';
}
</script>
```

I've been trying with `evaluateJavaScript`, but was not able to retrieve the coordinates. I tried to created a function to access the position with `marker.getPosition()`, but with no luck. The dummy below works though..

```
newplace = QWebView.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(QString('dummyTxt()'))

>>> print newplace.toString()
This works.
```

Any suggestions on how to get the coordinates back to Qt?

**Edit:**

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
def update_geo(self):
    # Capture coordinates of the last marker on the map.
    mark = self.map.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript('document.getElementById("markerlocation").value').toString()
    # Convert string to list of floats, stripping parentheses.
    marker = str(mark).strip('()').split(', ')
    decimals = [float(c) for c in marker]
```

Full source in https://github.com/nelas/veliger/blob/master/veliger.py#L2374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around to make it work but I'm not pretty sure that it will be the right approach. Anyway, this is what I did:

1. Create a hidden input in the body section of your html document to save the position data of the marker:

   ```
   <body>
       (...)
       <input id="locationData" type="hidden">
       (...)
   </body>
   ```
2. In the javascript code, save the position of the marker in the hidden input every time it's created:

   ```
   function placeMarker(location) {
       (...)
       document.getElementById("locationData").value = marker.position;
       (...)
   }
   ```
3. In your Qt code, read the value of the hidden input with the instruction:

   ```
   webView->page()->mainFrame()->findFirstElement("#locationData").evaluateJavaScript("this.value").toString();
   ```

I hope it helps!

Source: http://opendocs.net/qt/4.6/webkit-formextractor.html

Comment: Thank you, Mkfnx. It helped indeed! I only changed the Qtcode to find the element directly via js: webview.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript('document.getElementById("markerlocation").value').toString()

Comment: I hadn't noticed the javascript alternative. I'm glad to see it helped!